# Spring Roo 1.2.5 generates invalid code for nested annotations

Tags: spring-roo

Given the code sample:

```
final ClassOrInterfaceTypeDetailsBuilder cidBuilder = new ClassOrInterfaceTypeDetailsBuilder(javaTypeDetails);
...
FieldMetadataBuilder field = ...;
...
final AnnotationMetadataBuilder newAnnotationMetadata = new AnnotationMetadataBuilder(JpaJavaType.JOIN_TABLE);
newAnnotationMetadata.addStringAttribute("name", joinTableName);
List<NestedAnnotationAttributeValue> valueList;
AnnotationMetadataBuilder nestedAnnotationMetadata;
if (joinColumnName != null) {
    valueList = new ArrayList<NestedAnnotationAttributeValue>(1);
    nestedAnnotationMetadata = new AnnotationMetadataBuilder(JpaJavaType.JOIN_COLUMN);
    nestedAnnotationMetadata.addStringAttribute("name", joinColumnName);
    valueList.add(new NestedAnnotationAttributeValue(new JavaSymbolName("value"), nestedAnnotationMetadata.build()));
    newAnnotationMetadata.addAttribute(new ArrayAttributeValue<NestedAnnotationAttributeValue>(
            new JavaSymbolName("joinColumns"), valueList));
}
if (inverseJoinColumnName != null) {
    valueList = new ArrayList<NestedAnnotationAttributeValue>(1);
    nestedAnnotationMetadata = new AnnotationMetadataBuilder(JpaJavaType.JOIN_COLUMN);
    nestedAnnotationMetadata.addStringAttribute("name", inverseJoinColumnName);
    valueList.add(new NestedAnnotationAttributeValue(new JavaSymbolName("value"), nestedAnnotationMetadata.build()));
    newAnnotationMetadata.addAttribute(new ArrayAttributeValue<NestedAnnotationAttributeValue>(
            new JavaSymbolName("inverseJoinColumns"), valueList));
}
field.addAnnotation(newAnnotationMetadata.build());
```

This produces invalid annotation on field, like:

```
@JoinTable(name = "NOTICE_EVENT_RECEIVER_X", joinColumns = { @javax.persistence.JoinColumn("NOTICE_EVENT_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @javax.persistence.JoinColumn("NOTICE_RECEIVER_ID") })
```

As you can see, attribute "name" of JoinColumn annotation is missing and code is not compilable.
Am I doing something wrong or it is a Roo bug?

UPD: There is definately a **roo bug: when number of annotation attributes is 1 - assumed it is always a "value" attribute**. This assumption is wrong! Workaround is to specify one more attribute. For example (in my scenario)   "nullable". I this case produced code is compilable.

Answer (score 0):

Please, contribute your fix to Roo via GitHub pull request : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-roo/pulls